# Double render error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure how its possible to get this error :

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError users#create
```

When in my controller I got this code :

```
render 'new' and return
```

I got the log from the bugsnag saying that I got the error at this line.

This is the create method code :

```
def create
    back_button and return if params[:back_button]

    @profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:user])

    if @profile.nil? || current_user.nil? || @profile.user.nil?
      sign_out
      redirect_to signup_path and return
    end

    if @profile.new_record?
      render 'new' and return
    else
      redirect_to more_questions_path and return
    end
end
```

I have before filter in this controller :

```
before_filter :signed_in_user

def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end
```

Comment: Do you have a render before this line?

Comment: can you add code for `create` action? It seems that you are somehow calling render twice via create action.

Comment: Do you have any before or after filters in either this or some parent controller (including `ApplicationController`) that could be doing something odd?

Comment: I have updated the question, i do have before filter

Comment: Actually I realized my question was somewhat dumb, because rendering or redirecting from a before_filter halts the filter chain and prevents your action from being run (assuming Rails version not < 2), which it seems is what you're doing. Are you catching (rescuing from) any exceptions and doing custom rendering, or anything like that somewhere?

Comment: Can you try `redirect_to signup_path` then have `return` on a separate line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create
    return back_button if params[:back_button]

    @profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:user])

    if @profile.nil? || current_user.nil? || @profile.user.nil?
      sign_out
      return redirect_to signup_path
    end

    if @profile.new_record?
      render 'new'
    else
      redirect_to more_questions_path
    end
  end

  private

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      return redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end
end
```

The reasoning behind it: `x and return` means `x and return nil`, thus returns `nil`. Actually, you try to short-circuit the controller action, and `return redirect_to ...`.

Comment: For education's sake, even if it returned `nil`, why wouldn't that return from the method, rather than continuing to parse the block to render or redirect again?

Comment: @AdamGrant [4 ways to early return from a rails controller](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/4-ways-to-early-return-from-a-rails-controller/)

Comment: Thanks for that resource, @ThomasKlemm, but I didn't see any points made about why returning nil would still let the remainder of the block execute. There are a few places that support my inquiry, "Now it sounds better verify_order or return. Either the order is verified or we return early"

To be clear, I understand that a `render :blah and return` won't do what you want, but not why it would allow the block to continue.

Answer (score 6):

The `and` isn't doing anything for you.

In each place where you have `xxx and return`, replace it with

```
xxx
return
```

For example:

```
redirect_to signup_path
return
```

That should work more like you would expect it to.

Comment: it's not the same as `return redirect_to`?

Comment: What's the explanation for this? I have one action that is causing a double render error over AJAX while every other endpoint used for AJAX works just fine. I just spent two days trying to figure this out, and a simple return after the respond_to block works...Rails 5 y'all

Comment: @albaba The `and` short circuts if the statement before it returns `false` or `nil`. There's no advantage to using the `and` since just returning on the next line accomplishes the stopping of the controller logic to avoid rendering again just fine.

Comment: @Coenwulf That makes sense. I guess I'm mainly just curious why AJAX works with other actions perfectly fine, while with this one action / endpoint in particular causes a double render (requiring the return).

Comment: @albaba To figure that out I'd have to look at your specific code. Usually double render errors are caused because you have a code path that conditionally sends some response and then have more code after it intended to handle other conditions, but you failed to add a return statement after conditionally responding.

Answer (score 3):

You have a render and a redirect. You have to pick one.

Comment: the presence of `and return` after those `render` or `redirect_to` lines should prevent further execution in the action, should it not?

Comment: no. I thought like this once. Do you come from a C/C++ background? :) Anyways, the return doesn't mean what you think it means. You can either have render or redirect but not both. Rails has had that constraint for a long time.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow you. You're right of course about the render/redirect constraint (or even render/render, redirect/redirect, etc), but in regards to `return`, I just did a test, and `and return` or even just `return` does indeed do what I thought it does, which is to return from the method (the action in this case). In Gandalf's scenario, according to his code, execution in that action should arrive at one of the render or redirect lines, and "shall not pass" beyond that point. You said it "doesn't mean what you think it means", so what affect do you think it has in this case?

Comment: there is a big difference between & and 'and' and in this case "and return" is not same as "& return". The return statement doesn't get executed unless the render returns true. What does that render or redirect_to return? I don't actually know but I'm going to guess it doesn't return a boolean value (or an expression that could be a boolean). Anyways, what I'm saying is: doing render "and return" is not the same as (in C) 'if 1==1 return;'

Comment: For clarity, I assume when you say `&`, you mean `&&` (the logical AND, not bitwise AND), correct? Assuming yes, both `render` and `redirect_to` do indeed return something. I don't know when they would return something "falsey" but it **should** execute the return, because anything non-nil in Ruby is considered "true" for boolean evaluation (truthy). Also, if you check out a lot of [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors), more frequently these days they seem to advise this method. I personally dislike it, but it is technically legal.

Comment: how can I pick one? how will I render model errors if I redirect? and how will I render if the user is invalid

Comment: I would redirect to something like /users/new should be equivalent as render 'new' right?

Comment: @Teeg I agree. My knowledge of controller actions is not so deep to address that though.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `redirect_to signup_path` is returning either `nil` or `false`, thus your `and return` is not being executed.

You can fix this many ways, the simplest is replace

```
redirect_to signup_path and return
```

by

```
redirect_to signup_path
return
```

Yet, I suggest you to do a bigger change. Try changing this

```
if @profile.nil? || current_user.nil? || @profile.user.nil?
  sign_out
  redirect_to signup_path and return
end

if @profile.new_record?
  render 'new' and return
else
  redirect_to more_questions_path and return
end
```

By

```
if @profile.nil? || current_user.nil? || @profile.user.nil?
  sign_out
  redirect_to signup_path
elsif @profile.new_record?
  render 'new'
else
  redirect_to more_questions_path
end
```

This way it is clear that only one path can be taken, without relying on return.