# Getting DoubleRenderError when doing `update_resource` for devise within ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I'm trying to allow devise's user account to be updated without requiring the password to be changed every time you change a user account. To do this requires me to change the `update_resource` method but I'm getting a `DoubleRenderErrror` and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here's my code as it stands:

```
  controller do 
    protected
    def update_resource(resource, params)
      if params.first[:password].blank?
        resource.update_without_password(params.first)
      else
         resource.update_attributes(params.first)
      end
      if resource.errors.blank?
        redirect_to admin_users_path, :notice => "User updated successfully."
      else
         render :edit
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

try replacing the existing code `redirect_to admin_users_path, :notice => "User updated successfully."` with `return redirect_to admin_users_path, :notice => "User updated successfully."`. I hope this will help.

Comment: You can find a solution to similar problem here also. 
[link_here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610090/double-render-error-rails)

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was thinking the method `update_resource` I was overriding was an override itself for the `update` method when it's not, as a result, it was running my override, then running the `update` method thus rendering/redirecting twice.

Removing all the rendering/redirect_to stuff solved the problem.

I realised my mistake after seeing [this issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2457#issue-19014133) on GitHub, specifically this code snippet:

```
def update_resource(object, attributes)
  puts "==================before update====================="
  debugger
  object.update_attributes(*attributes)
  puts "=================after update====================="
end    
def update(options={}, &block)
  super do |success, failure| 
    block.call(success, failure) if block
    failure.html { render :edit }
  end
end
```

as you can see, the update method and the update_resource methods are separate methods.