# Render multilpe times - Double render in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to avoid this double render issue, i have been trying to replicate but couldn't. So is there any issue with this below code?

```
def check_count
  assign_values_from_params
  if count >= failed_count
    render partial: params[:view_name], layout: false and return
  else
    render text: 'works' and return
  end
end


def assign_values_from_params
  # code
  # code
  # code
  if @date.blank?
    redirect_to main_index_path and return
  end

  if @counted_obj != 5
    # call one function
  end
end
```

Also should i try something this way [Double render error rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610090/double-render-error-rails) ?

Comment: I wonder why do you get double rendering errors in the first place. The code in your question cannot produce that error because there is only one `render` call per branch. I think your question is missing some relevant code. Can you please post the error message and the stack trace.

Comment: I have updated the code @spickermann

Comment: You are calling `redirect_to` in a helper method, returning from the helper,  and then continuing execution and calling `render`. Hence the double render--once with `redirect_to` and once with `render`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call [`performed?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-performed-3F) to check if `render` or `redirect` has already been called.

You might want to change your to code to something like this:

```
def check_count
  assign_values_from_params
  
  return if performed?

  if count >= failed_count
    render(partial: params[:view_name], layout: false)
  else
    render(text: 'works')
  end
end

def assign_values_from_params
  # code

  if @date.blank?
    redirect_to(main_index_path) and return
  end

  # code
end
```

Comment: I was trying to replicate with this performed? before put the solution,  luckly i got the real error now and it shows <html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/main">redirected</a>.</body></html> ?

Comment: How do you request the page? Normal HTML GET, via JavaScript? What content type does your browser expected? It looks like `check_count` doesn't return valid HTML, whereas the `redirect_to` needs a normal HTML request to work properly? But I would say that is a different problem/error and you might want to open a new question for that one.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the return statement from `render partial: params[:view_name], layout: false and return` as after render it will lead to return nil. Remove the return statement from both lines and it should be fixed.

It should look something like this `render text: 'works'`.

Comment: Are you sure this will resolve this issue?, because i couldn't replicate this also before we had this issue and we put it this way

Answer (score 2):

According to me first, check whether any render is being called. As going through your code it is not showing but maybe internally it is being called. So You can call performed? in your controller to check if render  was already called:

```
performed?               # => false
render partial: params[:view_name], layout: false
performed?               # => true
```

If calling performed? says true for the first time then you have to check your code.

Comment: Let me try that way

Answer (score 1):

Using `return` after render will return `nil` so i suggest you to remove `return` from both render , which should look like this.

  `if tmp_count >= failed_count
    render partial: params[:view_name], layout: false
  else
    render text: 'works'
  end`

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works for you.

```
def check_count
  assign_values_from_params

end


def assign_values_from_params
  # code
  # code
  # code
  if @date.blank?
    redirect_to main_index_path and return
  else
    if @counted_obj != 5
      # call one function
    end

    if count >= failed_count
      render partial: params[:view_name], layout: false and return
    else
      render text: 'works' and return
    end
  end

end
```